# Chrome GPU crash recovery for canvas, Detecting hardware failure

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, canvas

Every now and then the GPU task on chrome crashes. It returns but all the images rendered by the app are lost. The crash is caused by GPU over heating (laptop).

The run up to the crash is very unfriendly, a simple task that should take no more than 1/10th of a second slows right down and locks the tab, then locks the browser, then locks the mouse, and the entire system. The Laptop is completely unresponsive (apart from power down) for more then 2-3 minuets. When it finally returns (and the javascript function has completed) all my images and canvases are blank.

Is there a way to get information on the Chrome tasks so that I know if a particular task (GPU) has recovered from a crash.

Is there a way to know if the computer is throttling hardware to keep cool? I would like to be able to reduce load on the system when it is having problems, but only when it has problems.

Below is an example of the code that will without fail completely lock up two Toshiba laptops if the image/canvas being processed is over around 1Mpix.

What frustrates me most is that Firefox has no problems with the same code and when chrome is up fresh from a boot it does not care as well.

```
// last crash was on 1360 by 2048 canvas with 2d context
var x3,x3a,z3a,lines, z3, dd;  // 
// img is a canvas object
// imgSrc is either the canvas or image being transformed
if(type === "PerspectiveUpDown"){ 
    morpherData.requiersUpdate = false;
    var x1 = pointNew[1].x;              // top left corner
    var y1 = pointNew[1].y;
    var x2 = pointNew[2].x;              // top right corner
    var y2 = pointNew[2].y;
    var hh = (x2 - x1) / (y2 - y1);      // Slope of left edge
    var w2 = w / 2;                      // half width
    var z1 = w2 - x1;                    // Distance (z) to first line
    var z2 = (z1 / (w2 - x2)) * z1 - z1; // distance (z) between first and last line
    for (var y = y1; y < y2; y++) {      // for each line
        x3 = ((y - y1) * hh) + x1;       // get scan line top left edge
        x3a = (((y+1) - y1) * hh) + x1;  // get scan line bottom left edge
        z3 = (z1 / (w2 - x3)) * z1;      // get Z distance to top of this line
        z3a = (z1 / (w2 - x3a)) * z1;      // get Z distance to bottom of this line
        dd = ((z3 - z1) / z2) * h;       // get y bitmap coord
        lines = ((z3a - z1) / z2) * h-dd;       // get number oh lines to copy
        img.ctx.drawImage(imgSrc, 0, dd % h, w, lines, x3, y, w - x3 * 2, 1);
    }
    img.processed = true;        

}else
```

Comment: so it does work on chrome after rebooting, but later when you try again it will fail ?

Comment: @dwana It is very much dependent on the GPU load. As I understand it the drivers will reduce the clock frequency of the GPU if they get to hot, then at some stage (and I am guessing) chrome switches to software rendering. Boot up has it running ok for a bit, but boot up give it time to cool down. It would be nice to know when I should reduce the load so I never get to the crash stage.

Comment: You might be able to use rAF to check the load.  As to why this is only in chrome i don't know. My only quess would be that any program uses cpu, so any program can put load on the system. And FF could limit the amount of memory (of a single tab).